# If not contain specific text = TRUE in UDF

Tags: excel, vba

I need help to fix this UDF.

I need the result to be "Salentein Malbec" when
Familia is different from "ESPUMOSO" (done)
Marca is equal to "SALENTEIN"(done)
Cepa is equal to "MALBEC" (done)
Formato is equal to "B0750" (done)
Material does not contain the characters "TDF" (pending, i need help with this part)

```
Function PRODUCTDESCRIPTION(Familia, Marca, Cepa, Formato, Material)

If Familia <> "ESPUMOSO" And Marca = "SALENTEIN" And Cepa = "MALBEC" And Formato = "B0750" And Material <> "*TDF*" Then
    PRODUCTDESCRIPTION = "Salentein Malbec"

End If

End Function
```

Comment: Either use `Not Like`, or use `InStr` to check if the text is present or not.

Comment: To clarify Bigben's comment, you cannot use wildcards like this ""*TDF*"".  It is better to be specific and test for the absence of the substring e.g. Instr(Material, "TDF")=0

Comment: ... more detail, you can use wildcards with `Not Like`, but you can't use them with `<>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this because of having a problem in the last part I am showing you that, you can use it in VBA also.

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("TDF",D7))
```

[image: The final Result]

Here is how you can do it in VBA, I have created a function for that just for testing, you can implement that in your code.

simply you can use **InStr(whereTo, word)** and it returns the position where the word is located at

```
InStr(whereTo, word) // return integer number.
```

here is a sample I have created for you.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   
     Call SearchForWord("TDF", Sheet1.Range("D6"))
        
End Sub


Sub SearchForWord(word As String, whereTo As Range)

    Dim foundAt As Integer
    foundAt = InStr(whereTo, word)
    
    If foundAt > 0 Then
        TextBox1.Text = word + " has found at " + CStr(foundAt)
        MsgBox "Cell not contain " + word + " at " + CStr(foundAt)
    Else
        TextBox1.Text = word + " has not found at " + CStr(foundAt)
        MsgBox "Cell not contains " + word
    End If

End Sub
```

[image: VBA result]